# How to send sms to customers mobiles using Azure Notification Hub with R?

Tags: r, azure, sms

I want send sms notification to customer mobiles using azure notification hub with R.I tried with twilio but in twilio we have to register mobile numbers first,I can't send messages with unregistered numbers.That's why i chosed azure notification hub.Can you suggest me how to send messages to android using azure notification hub with R?

Tried in twilio:

```
Sys.setenv(TWILIO_SID = "xxxxxxxxxxx")
Sys.setenv(TWILIO_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
#  store the numbers in some variables
my_phone_number <- "zzzzzzzzzz" ###n user's number
twilios_phone_number <- "zzzzzzzzzz" ### given number by twilio

# Now we can send away!
tw_send_message(from = twilios_phone_number, to = my_phone_number, 
                body = "Hello from R ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure notification hub does not provide SMS messaging. It works with push notifications, but to leverage those, you need to have a mobile app in place. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq) you can find more details.

Comment: Thank you for responding @kgalic. Do you have Any idea about how to send sms to mobile without creating mobile app using R?

Comment: Unfortunately, I also know for twilio and have some experience with Logic apps and Twilio, but I cannot tell what would be an alternative so that you do not have to register the number..